# Count Up jQuery Timer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, stopwatch

I am trying to use this jQuery count up script https://github.com/robcowie/jquery-stopwatch but i would like to add an event that if the timer goes over 2 minutes that the BG color of the #demo1 div would change to red

I have added in all of the code on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FeWrD/

Comment: I'd try to modify the `defaultFormatMilliseconds` function. This plugin should implement a `tick` callback as well.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('#demo1').stopwatch().bind('tick.stopwatch', function(e, elapsed){
>   if (elapsed >= 120000) {
>      $("#demo1").css("background", "red");
>   } }).stopwatch('start')
> })
> ```

from documentation

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind it to **tick.stopwatch event.**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#demo1').stopwatch().bind('tick.stopwatch', function(e, elapsed) {
        if (elapsed <= 5000) {
            $("#demo1").css("background", "green");
        }
        else {
            $("#demo1").css("background", "orange");
        }
    }).stopwatch('start') ;
});
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FeWrD/2/)**